# Stack every nth column under neath each other

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

This may be a trivial problem however I am unable to figure it out. I have a dataset which has duplicate columns and I need to figure out a way to stack every nth column underneath each other. So if we consider this :

[image: original data]

We can see we have duplicate columns, I need my data to stack underneath each other like this :

[image: after]

My duplicate columns are a constant, so I will always have 5 duplicate columns. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just cut the second set of records and paste them below the first?

Comment: Reason why I am not doing that is because I have about 30k columns. I just edited it down just to show an example what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Got it. That's a terrific reason not to do it that way.

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: Yup haha and I have 37 rows

Comment: Is each row populated with data in every column?

Comment: Yes no blank cells or columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You need a cyclical `OFFSET` formula here.

### SETUP

So we have a header row, and data in, let's say, `A2:ZZZZ38`. We'll just put this on `Sheet1`. We'll set up our output on `Sheet2`.

### PRECIS

Conceptually, we can easily understand that we want `Sheet2!A2` (hereafter we'll just call this cell `A2` for simplicity) to reproduce `Sheet1!A2`. In `A3` we want the next cell down, and so on - until we've looked at all the records in `Sheet1!A`, and then we want to go back to the first row, but over 5 columns.

This is clearly a case for `OFFSET`.

### FORMULA

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!A$2,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-1),ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-2)/(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-1),0)*5)`

### DEMO

My data is quite a bit smaller than yours; just big enough to prove concept.

Here's `Sheet1`:

[image]

And the output `Sheet2`:

[image]

### EXPLANATION

`OFFSET` has three parts. Where to start, how many rows to go down (the vertical offset), and how many columns to go over (horizontal offset).

#### A - where to start

`Sheet1!A$2`

Pretty straightforward.

#### B - rows offset

`MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-1)`

Find out what row we're on and subtract 2 (we're starting in `A2`, and we want `A2` to be the zero offset). Divide that by how many records we're counting off (the `-1` here accounts for the header row showing up), and take the remainder. This simply produces a function that counts from `0` to `[n-1]` where *n* is the number of rows, and then starts again at 0.

In other words, for a table with 8 records, this returns:

`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0 ...`

#### C - columns offset

`ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-2)/(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-1),0)*5`

Take `ROW()-2` again, and divide it by the record count again - but this time instead of taking the `MOD` (remainder) of that relationship, we just want to round it down to the nearest integer. This gives us a sequence consisting of a number of 0's equal to the record count, followed by a number of 1's, 2's, etc. Then multiply that by 5 (see note below). This provides our column offset - every time the cyclical row count resets, we jump over another 5 columns.

In other words, for a table with 8 records, this returns:

`0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10 ...`

### FORMULA, AGAIN:

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!A$2,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-1),ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-2)/(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-1),0)*5)`

This goes into `Sheet2!A2` and copies across for `A:E` and down without restriction.

### NB

1. The 5 is hard-coded, because you stated as a property of your data that the columns repeat by 5. This could be expanded into a dynamic function, if needed (or, of course, simply changed if there is a fixed number of repeated columns that isn't 5). That can be a question for another day.
2. Despite the massive file size, this formula shouldn't take any time to process. It does include an entire column reference, but inside a `COUNTA` I don't *think* that will slow you down. If it does, you can easily change each instance of `COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)` to `COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A38)` since technically we already know the size of the data, or even simply hard code that value to 37, which will work as long as you have exactly 37 rows.
3. Half the time it took me to get this right was being careful with order of arithmetic operations and splitting out the parts of the formula into different columns to troubleshoot the problem I was having - which turned out to be a missing pair of parentheses. At its core, this is actually very simple; it's just a matter of knowing that `OFFSET` exists and then working out the logic/arithmetic to understand how to produce the sequence of pairs you need to offset by.

Comment: Good answer, and I was going to upvote it anyway.  But the clincher was using "Precis", and not as a typo.  :-)

Comment: Not sure I can convey how much I appreciate this... thank you so much for the thorough and highly detailed answer. Not only does it just work for me but I can now take OFFSET and use it else where (Didn't even know it existed!), thank you for your time!

Comment: Damn, thought I was reading one of my own answers there!