# Excel - convert a list of data into a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I am trying to find a solution that we have in relation to converting a list of information into a table. At present, we can only pull raw data from one of our systems into the following list:

```
DATE 1
NAME 1
GRADE 1
COST CENTRE 1
DATE 2
NAME 2
GRADE 2
COST CENTRE 2
```

I want to be able to quickly transpose multiple entries into a horizontal table with these headings. The issue is that there is no way of using the transpose function unless you do this one-by-one for all entries.

Is there a formulae that could be used to quickly put a list of data into a table for these headings?
Thanks

Comment: Questions about Google Spreadsheets are off topic and should be asked on webapps.stackexchange.com, unless they specifically involve your computer or browser.

Comment: If you do want to do this in Excel, and you want to use a formula, and the number of rows per record is consistent, you want a cyclical `OFFSET` formula. Here's one explanation of how to do this for columns not rows, that you should be able to adapt for your purpose: https://superuser.com/questions/1424891/stack-every-nth-column-under-neath-each-other/1424908#1424908 You should also be able to find other answers more specific to your need, I know there are many on Super User.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the list to Excel from text document? Then copy these cells again, paste to another location in Excel, choose Transpose as Paste Options.